# Change $actsAs variable from controller

Tags: cakephp, plugins, behavior, cakephp-2.2

All I want to do is change a value ('path') in the $actsAs array of my Upload model from the controller prior to a save.

The only way I've come up with that works is to unload the behavior and then load it with all of it's settings.

This seems like overkill to just change the path.  Is there an easier/better way?

```
$this->loadModel('Upload');
$this->Upload->Behaviors->unload('Upload.Upload');
$this->Upload->Behaviors->load('Upload.Upload', array(
    'photo' => array(
        'thumbnailSizes' => array(
            'xvga' => '1024x768',
            'vga' => '640x480',
            'thumb' => '80x80',
        ),
        'thumbnailMethod' => 'php',
        'thumbnailQuality' => '80',
        'pathMethod'=>'random',
        'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}uploads{DS}test{DS}{field}{DS}',
        'maxSize' => '5242880', //5MB
        'mimetypes' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/bmp'),
        'extensions' => array('jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp'),
    ),
));
if($this->Upload->save($this->request->data)) {
//...
```

Comment: interesting - through your question I found out that the attach() and detach() methods I have always been using seem to be deprecated (or at least only available for BC) - and that one should probably use load() and unload().

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source I think the [`uploadSettings()`](https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload/blob/2.0/Model/Behavior/UploadBehavior.php#L170) method is what you're looking for:

```
$this->Upload->uploadSettings('photo', 'path', 'YOUR_PATH');
```

Comment: Is there a way to change an $actsAs variable without using a plugin's method?

Answer (score 0):

The BehaviorCollection should merge the configuration when you load it over an existing behavior, so you shouldn't need to re-include all the other configuration. In fact, you shouldn't need to unload it either.

```
$this->Upload->Behaviors->load('Upload.Upload', array(
    'photo' => array(
        'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}uploads{DS}test{DS}{field}{DS}'
    )
));
```

Since the merging uses `array_merge` instead of `array_merge_recursive` this will not work for you. I included it here because it's probably the preferred method, though the behavior you're using uses a configuration array that Cake won't handle the way you want it to.

Alternatively, you can simply modify the `$actsAs` variable when the model is constructed, which will cause it to set up correctly.

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
  // 2 lines for readability
  $this->actsAs['Upload.Upload']['photo']['path'] = 
  '{ROOT}webroot{DS}uploads{DS}test{DS}{field}{DS}';
  return parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
}
```

Comment: I ignored the first way, since you say it won't work for me.  The 2nd way gives this error:  `Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property Upload::$Behavior has no effect [ROOT/cms.daveschwan.com/Controller/ArticleDatasController.php, line 44]`

Comment: Should be `Behaviors` (plural).

Comment: After changing to Behaviors plural:  `Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property BehaviorCollection::$settings has no effect [ROOT/cms.daveschwan.com/Controller/ArticleDatasController.php, line 44`

Comment: Sounds like the Upload behavior you are using doesn't make use of the settings array. What plugin are you using?

Comment: The solution may be to just overwrite the `$actsAs` variable on the model's constructor. It's far more hacky than the answer @dhofstet  gave, though. I've added that as an option in case you want to do it this way.